# Проблема с обращением к value переменной

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-faq

Прошу помочь в следующей проблеме:
Имеем select с набором option`ов. Стоит задача в выборе option, у которого value равняется переменной pack, но при этом следующая конструкция не работает:

```
var pack = "test"; 
$("#pack [value=pack]").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Хотя, если не обращаться к переменной, а статично задать value - все работает, пример:

```
$("#pack [value='test']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Вопрос: в чем ошибка в первой конструкции, что не так? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: попробуйте интерполировать строку. $("#pack [value=${pack}]") только вместо " указать нужно обратные кавычки `

Answer (score 0):

Во-втором варианте, когда ты проверяешь данный элемент на наличие

> `$("#pack [value='test']")`

Происходит выборка. Ты говоришь парсеру, что бы он элементу с `id pack` у которого `value='test'` сделал 
атрибут `selected="selected"`

> $("#pack [value='test']").attr("selected", "selected");

По этому и работает...

А в первом случае у тебя идет сравнение, что не правильно
А должна быть такая конструкция на сравнение

```
var pack = "test";

if ($("#pack").val() == pack){
    $("#pack").attr("selected", "selected");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

мой совет - научись работать со строками строки в JS)
правильный пример:

```
var pack = "test"; 
$("#pack [value='"+pack+"']").attr("selected", "selected");
```